# gstreamer: create rtp-stream out of mp4-file without transcoding

Tags: gstreamer

I wanted to create a RTP-stream of a mp4-file with gstreamer.
I am using gstreamer 1.18.4 on debian bullseye.

To create a mp4-file I recorded an RTSP-stream from my webcam using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.111.146/axis-media/media.amp" port-range=28000-38000 buffer-mode=0 latency=80 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=filename.mp4
```

After recording the file `filename.mp4` I tried to stream it using RTP:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=filename.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=50000 host=127.0.0.1
```

And the playback of the stream could be started using the following command on the same machine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=50000 auto-multicast=true ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Everything works as expected!

But since I don't want to transcode the file, I just wanted to skip the decoding and encoding part. Therefore, I created the following pipelines:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=filename.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=50000 host=127.0.0.1
```

and

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=filename.mp4 ! qtdemux ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=50000 host=127.0.0.1
```

However, if I retry the playback pipeline (the pipeline with `udpsrc`) on both pipelines the stream is not displayed.
Interestingly, `nload` shows network traffic on `lo`.
What is wrong with the streaming pipelines?
Did I miss some magic-plugin in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found an answer to my question.

Changing the stream-server-pipeline from

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=filename.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=50000 host=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=filename.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=50000 host=127.0.0.1
```

solves the issue.

Thus, the difference is setting the parameter `config-interval=-1` for `h264parse`.